# Передать переменную из функции в функцию

Tags: javascript

```
function randomSelect() {
  randomBeer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    popUp[number].style.visibility = 'visible';
    popUp[number].style.transform = 'scaleY(1)';
    return number;
  })
}


function closeRandomSelect() {
  var randSelNumb = randomSelect();
  console.log(randSelNumb);   
}
```

Как можно передать переменную number в функцию function closeRandomSelect()?
Переменная number генерирует рандомное число, которое я хочу передать в другую функцию и продолжить с ним работу. Попытался вышеизложенным способом - не вышло.

Comment: Вопрос решил, но при помощи одной функции. Но ради интереса хотелось бы все-таки задействовать две функции и узнать, как это делается

Answer (score 0):

Возможно создать еще 1 глобальную переменную, присвоить ей значение переменной number, и дальше уже работать с созданной переменной (в С++ так делаю) . Может в javascript по другому )

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант: (доработка вашего способа)

```js
function randomSelect() {
  var number;
  
  randomBeer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    popUp[number].style.visibility = 'visible';
    popUp[number].style.transform = 'scaleY(1)';
  })
  
  return number;
}


function closeRandomSelect() {
  var randSelNumb = randomSelect();
  console.log(randSelNumb);
}

closeRandomSelect();
```

Но на самом деле, выходит что-то очень глупое, по-этому давайте попробуем сделать, красивее:

(Вы описали, что функция `randomSelect()` (далee `randomValue`) генерирует число, тогда для чего мы создаем обработчик событий? Не будем делать этого, а просто вернем число.)

```js
function randomValue() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
}

function closeRandomSelect() {
  var randSelNumb = randomValue();
  
  randomBeer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popUp[randSelNumb].style.visibility = 'visible';
    popUp[randSelNumb].style.transform = 'scaleY(1)';
  })
  
  console.log(randSelNumb);
}
```

А также можно использовать вот такой способ передачи:

```js
function randomValue() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
}

function closeRandomSelect(number) {

  randomBeer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    popUp[number].style.visibility = 'visible';
    popUp[number].style.transform = 'scaleY(1)';
  })
  
  console.log(number);
}

//       -------\/-------
closeRandomSelect(randomValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomSelect(callback) {
  randomBeer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    popUp[number].style.visibility = 'visible';
    popUp[number].style.transform = 'scaleY(1)';
    callback(number);
  })
}


function closeRandomSelect() {
  randomSelect(function(number){ 
    console.log(number);   
  });
}
```

Comment: Разве это будет работать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Нет, конечно (.